# Wrong syntax near LIKE clause in MariaDB

Tags: mysql, spring, mariadb, jpql, mysql-error-1064

I have a syntax error near the like clause, but I assume it's because of the functions I used on the same line.

```
(:#{#criteria.nameWithCompany} is null " +
            "                       or (lower(function('replace',u.fullName,' ','')) like :#{#criteria.nameWithCompany}) " +
            "                       or (concat(lower(function('replace',u.fullName,' ','')), '/', " +
            "                function('replace', lower(c.companyName), ' ', '')) like :#{#criteria.nameWithCompany}))
```

This is my class for custom functions, since JPA doesn't have them.

```
public class MySQLUTF8InnoDBDialect implements MetadataBuilderContributor {

    @Override
    public void contribute(MetadataBuilder metadataBuilder) {
        metadataBuilder.applySqlFunction("group_concat_with_distinct", new SQLFunctionTemplate(StringType.INSTANCE, "group_concat(distinct ?1)"));
        metadataBuilder.applySqlFunction("replace", new SQLFunctionTemplate(StringType.INSTANCE, "replace"));
        metadataBuilder.applySqlFunction("char_length", new SQLFunctionTemplate(StringType.INSTANCE, "char_length"));

    }
}
```

This is the error message I am getting.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
> near ') like '%:#{#criteria.nameWithCompany}' or
> concat(lower(replace), '/', replac...' at line 1

I have tried everything to fix this, but I still get the same error everytime I make a request.

Comment: Look closer where your `(` are beginning and not ending.

Comment: You'd need to show us the actual SQL query generated by your code